# Which is most critical? 警報 or 注意報?

Tags: word-choice, nuances

A disaster warning app asks me whether I want notifications for 警報 or for 注意報 or both.

First I signed up for both, but it sends me notifications about inconsequential things such as air dryness. So I would like to receive notifications only for the most dangerous stuff like powerful typhoons.

Which is most critical? 警報 or 注意報?

Both translate to "warning" in my dictionary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the weather warning context, 警報 is more critical than 注意報. Currently the Met Agency defines three alert levels: 特別警報, 警報, and 注意報, for each translated by them *Emergency Warning*, *Warning*, and *Advisory*. They are usually painted with purple, red, and yellow colors on a map.

Also see: [Forecast Services](http://www.jma.go.jp/jma/en/Activities/forecast.html) (the JMA site)

Comment: Some additional information that the OP might find helpful: The Kanji "警" means _warn_, whereas "注意" means _notice_. "特別" from "特別警報" in this answer means _special_. I would assume that a _special warning_ is higher priority than a _warning_, which in turn is higher priority than a _notice_.

Answer (score 2):

警 means "Warning" or "caution"; 注意 means "Attention"
;報 means a "report" or "Notice"

I am trying to provide a word-by-word break down to give you more insights, hope it helps :)